# Using smart_selects / jQuery to change choice field

Tags: jquery, python, django, django-forms

I have a form configured that displays a list of users. Currently this displays everyone from the default user auth model in Django:

`employee = models.ForeignKey(User)`

I also have extended the 'User' model to contain some extra fields against the user (client, location, holiday days etc).

`class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, blank=False)
    location = models.ForeignKey(Location, blank=False)`

However, I'd like to do the following:

If the previous choices (client, location) are set to Client1 and Japan, only show users that are set for this client and location.

I've tried using smart selects, but I don't think this was designed to work like this (or, if it is, I'm not understanding it correctly and the documentation is really lacking).

`employee = ChainedForeignKey(
        Employee, 
        chained_field="client",
        chained_model_field="user", 
        show_all=False, 
        auto_choose=True
    )`

I think I'm going about this the completely wrong way and I can't figure out an appropriate way to do this in Django.

Does anyone have a recommended plugin that I can use that might be smart enough to do this? I know the question seems like I'm just asking for the code, but really I just have no idea what I'm doing wrong with everything I've tried. Even just a recommendation would be great.

To summarise my question: **How can I ask Django to filter my form results based on the previously selected field?**

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, Django doesn't support this.

You can set up additional views and use jquery to send ajax requests to narrow the responses of the 2nd and 3rd fields.

A quick google search brings up [django-ajax-selects](https://github.com/crucialfelix/django-ajax-selects), which looks like it does exactly what you want.

[Another](http://www.devinterface.com/blog/en/2011/02/how-to-implement-two-dropdowns-dependent-on-each-other-using-django-and-jquery/), albeit, slightly older solution.

Comment: Yeah I had a play with Ajax solutions and these seem like another better solution in the grander scheme. Will try out recommendation on the Ajax select.